# Guest question confirmation page

Tags: support

Please post a screenshot of (or link to) the help page that is shown to new users before they ask a question.

Comment: incognito mode is really that hidden?

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=anon_ask&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2fask

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice

Note that this differs from https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask-advice which redirects to https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask, both of which are linked to in various places but *not* shown as an interstitial ("EULA"-style) page for new askers.

Also note that this interstitial page is only shown to new askers on *some* sites, generally those that have a lot of new users who don't search and/or research their questions.